# Why do not you upload the images in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phaser-framework

I'm trying to upload images to Phaser in order to create an application.

I created a server with node.js
but they do not load the images, it loads a black background with a square in the center.

***I edit the question:***

I have added the html code where it is called Phaser.
Phaser install it with npm and function perfectly as you sample the console.
I show the image of the console on the network, as they suggested.
I hope this helps the companions to be able to help me, if I have to add more, they should just tell me.
[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj8ZO.png)

The Chrome inspector does not give me any errors, it shows that Phaser normally charges.
I have changed the configuration of my server several times without success, finally use one that I saw in another site.

This is my server.js file and the code that should be loaded.

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request ', request.url)

    var filePath = '.' + request.url
    if (filePath == './') {
        filePath = './index.html'
    }

    var extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase()
    var mimeTypes = {
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.js': 'text/javascript',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.json': 'application/json',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
        '.gif': 'image/gif',
        '.wav': 'audio/wav',
        '.mp4': 'video/mp4',
        '.woff': 'application/font-woff',
        '.ttf': 'application/font-ttf',
        '.eot': 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
        '.otf': 'application/font-otf',
        '.svg': 'application/image/svg+xml'
    }

    var contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'application/octet-stream'

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8')
                })
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Lo sentimos, consulte con el administrador del sitio para el error: '+error.code+' ..\n')
                response.end()
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })
            response.end(content, 'utf-8')
        }
    })

}).listen(3000);
console.log('server corriendo en el puerto 3000')
```

All the files are in the same folder, because I had the images and html files in different folders, but it did not work either.
I found several questions on the site similar to mine, but none is the same, and I found no solution in them.

Can you give me any idea why the image is not loaded?

Thanks, I hope to show enough and clearly explain my goals.

***Edit:
I show you the folder structure of my project:***

In the main folder of the project are files package.json, server.js
and a folder with the images and the index.html file

```
Phaser-tuto1 {

  package.json
  server.js
  public(folder) [

      -index.html
      -sky.png
      -platform-png
      -start.png
      -bomb.png
      -dude.png
   ]
}
```

I hope to clarify with this how my project is distributed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 1</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            scene: {
                preload: preload,
                create: create,
                update: update
            }
        };

        var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

        function preload() {
            this.load.image('sky', 'sky.png')

        }

        function create() {
            this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky')
        }

        function update() {
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your Phaser configuration and code as well? Specifically, how you're attempting to load the images.

Comment: It would also be useful to look at the Console and/or Network (or equivalent) tabs in your browser's web developer tools. These should tell you the path it's looking in.

Comment: Your Phaser setup looks correct -- so maybe the image isn't being loaded where you think it should be? Have you tried displaying it in your HTML with a `<img>` tag to verify the presence of the image in your server?

Comment: Sure. Just place this above the `<script>` tag in your html file: `<img src="sky.png">` and reload your server. If the image displays above your Phaser game, the server is loading the image as you expect.

Comment: Hi @brae. I did what you told me and this is the result.
The image loads, but it is not seen, and the silhouette of an image is shown, as I show in the capture: https://ibb.co/YTQL5tV
I do not know what else to do.

Comment: OK. That means the path you're using to load your image is incorrect or the server has failed to load it. Can you share your project folder structure?

Comment: Thank you again for your support @brae, edit the question in the final part to put the distribution of files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I use express for something like this, so I'm 100% sure this is the answer, but no harm trying.

`this.load.image('sky', 'sky.png')` tries to go to __dirname/sky.png which you haven't established yet. In server.js, add the line

`if (filePath == './sky') {
     filePath = './sky.png'
 }`

In phaser, you would then write:

`this.load.image('sky', 'sky')`

---

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in phaser 3 you add image to scene dynamically from HTML Dom input

create a scene like this and do remeber to add dom container in game config

```
var Menu = new Phaser.Class({

    Extends: Phaser.Scene,
    key:'Menu',

    initialize:
    
    function Menu ()
    {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'Menu', active: false });
    },

    preload:function() {
        this.load.html('browse', 'assets/forms/browse-btn.html');
    },

    create:function(){
        var element = this.add.dom(220, 180).createFromCache('browse');
        element.setScale(2.3,2);
        element.setPerspective(800);
        element.addListener('change');
        element.on('change', function (event) {
            _this.loadImage(event.target.files[0]);
        });

    },
    loadImage:function(file){
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var name = file.name;
        const card = this.add.image(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, name);

        let loader = new Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin(this);
        loader.image(name, objectURL);
        loader.once(Phaser.Loader.Events.COMPLETE, () => {
            // texture loaded so use instead of the placeholder
            console.log("loaded successfully");
            card.setTexture(name)
        });
        loader.start();
    },



});
```